# Solve nonlinear differential equation $y'=a(y^{a-1} + (C-y)^{a-1})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My differential equation reads

\begin{align}
y'=a(y^{a-1} + (C-y)^{a-1})
\end{align}

where $a\in(0,1)$ is some scalar and $y(0)=1/C$ a constant.

- Can you guys hint me to the solution, if it exists?

Comment: If we write this equation in the Leibniz notation (which may be easier to see that it's separable), we have that
$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=a\left(y^{a-1}+(C-y)^{a-1}\right)$, which then seperates into $
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^{a-1}+(C-y)^{a-1}}=a\mathrm{d}x$

Solving the ODE is thus just solving this integral, which might take a bit of work.

Comment: @Mark. I suppose that *a bit of work* is supposed to be an understatement. Cheers.

Comment: Was it easier if we specified $ay^{a-1}=f'(y) \rightarrow y^a = f(y)$, which gives $[f'(y)+f'(C-y)]^{-1}dy=dx$.